# How to generate where-in query with subquery in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, subquery, union, where-in

I'm trying to generate this query with entity frameworks `dbContext` :

```
SELECT     id
FROM         menuitems
WHERE     (parent_id = 11)
UNION
SELECT     id
FROM         menuitems AS menuitems_2
WHERE     (parent_id IN
    (SELECT     id
    FROM          menuitems AS menuitems_1
    WHERE      (parent_id = 11)))
```

Table menuitems has 2 columns: id, parent_id

I tried this:

```
List<int> mi = ctx.MenuItems.Where(i => i.parent_id == this.id).Select(id => id.id)
.Union(ctx.MenuItems.Where(c => ctx.MenuItems
              .Where(i => i.parent_id == this.id).Select(id => id.id)
              .Contains((int)c.parent_id)).Select(id => id.id))
              .ToList();
```

but it is not working, becouse i getting folowing error:

```
 Unable to create a constant value of type 'Menuitem'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

Is there a way to generate this query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can break this down into two simpler queries:

```
List<int> allItems=new List<int>();
var items= menuitems.Where(m=>m.parent_id == 11).Select(m=>m.id);
var children= menuitems.Where(items.Contains(m=>m.parent_id)).Select(m=>m.id);
allItems.AddRange(items.ToList());
allItems.AddRange(children.ToList());
```

I am pretty sure that does the same thing you were tying to do. You can actually do this a one query like this:

```
List<int> allItems=new List<int>();
var items= menuitems.Where(m=>m.parent_id == 11).Select(m=>m.id)
allItems= items.Union(menuitems.Where(items.Contains(m=>m.parent_id)).Select(m=>m.id));
```

This query is run just once when allItems is returned. Even though it looks likw two queries, Linq does not run the query until the final object requests it.

Comment: thx for reply. I wonder if I can do it with one query... so the question is how to use sub-query with contains.

Comment: I added a union to this. Please select as answer if this is what you are looking for.